# Convert bmp to tiff, python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to do something simple, and i find this line of code in every post that explains how to convert bmp to tiff in python, but I'm not sure what happens, the tiff image never happens.

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open('./data/x.bmp')
img.save('x.tiff','tiff') #TypeError: argument 3 must be str, not int
img.save('x.tiff') #TypeError: argument 3 must be str, not int
img.save('x.tiff','.tiff') #KeyError: '.TIFF'
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert, try this

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('./data/x.bmp').convert('RGB')
img.save('x.tiff', format='TIFF', compression='tiff_lzw')
```

Update:

if this fails, check if you have `libtiff` correctly installed

```
from PIL import features
print(features.check('libtiff'))   # True
```

Comment: I was also looking at this question. I tried this solution and it didn't work. Same as first + second error message

Comment: It's something to do with the TIFF format. Converting to JPEG worked fine with this code.

Comment: @Namyts your right, the tiff file still has an error, need to investigate. In a generic case, this will be the right way to do the conversion

Comment: maybe it has to do with the `libtiff` extension or `compression` kwarg

Comment: It prints true, but still errors. Supposedly libtiff is only needed for writing compressed TIFF files. Looking at the documentation, I can't see why this wouldn't work...

Comment: it works when you specify a compression type,  not sure why defaults result in a key error yet

Comment: yeah, must be a bug with the module... Regardless, a workaround for no compression would be img.save('x.tiff',format='tiff',compression=None), so you should add that to your answer :)